# How to grouping Label In Char JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Hello i have problem using Chart JS. I want show grouping label in my chart i see another promblem in other question, but now i am not understand how to implment to my project. Exampe : in my chart show data 
7:00, 7:01, 7:02, 7:03, 7:04 but i just want 7:00, 8:00, if you not undertans see my image
[image]

i want like this

[image]

my JS

```
function tampilChart(data,labels){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx,{
      type:'line',
      data:{
        labels:labels,
        datasets : [{
          label:'Harga',
          backgroundColor:'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          borderColor:'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          data:data
        }],
      },
      options:{
        scales:{
          yAxes:[{
            ticks:{
              beginAtZero:true
            }
          }]
        }
      },
    });
}
isiChart();
function isiChart(){
      $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/topsis/admin/Menu/tampilChart",
        type:'post',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            var nilai =[];
            var label=[];
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                label[i]=data[i].hari;
                nilai[i] = data[i].harga;
            }
            tampilChart(nilai,label);
        }
      });
    }
```

My JSON

{"harga":17.79708432356102,"hari":"2020-03-23 08:32:45"},{"harga":17.591260378595486,"hari":"2020-03-23 08:38:49"},{"harga":17.61026854797192,"hari":"2020-03-23 08:42:55"},{"harga":17.80475850892087,"hari":"2020-03-23 08:46:09"},{"harga":17.400984669807688,"hari":"2020-03-23 08:53:59"},{"harga":17.46294725519658,"hari":"2020-03-23 08:59:48"},{"harga":17.474364994815666,"hari":"2020-03-23 09:04:57"},{"harga":17.66738555493817,"hari":"2020-03-23 09:09:21"},{"harga":17.16010419143489,"hari":"2020-03-23 09:15:50"},{"harga":17.59928014323995,"hari":"2020-03-23 09:20:37"},{"harga":17.286875855560602,"hari":"2020-03-23 09:29:02"},{"harga":17.146187228413567,"hari":"2020-03-23 09:35:12"},{"harga":17.38490758256079,"hari":"2020-03-23 09:39:03"},{"harga":17.15664324821635,"hari":"2020-03-23 09:44:28"},{"harga":17.192637780118307,"hari":"2020-03-23 09:49:15"},{"harga":17.62267025376745,"hari":"2020-03-23 09:54:10"},{"harga":17.723818283548656,"hari":"2020-03-23 09:59:53"},{"harga":17.71860964564134,"hari":"2020-03-23 10:04:00"},{"harga":17.73204012352615,"hari":"2020-03-23 10:09:24"},{"harga":17.768559437846704,"hari":"2020-03-23 10:11:15"},{"harga":17.993312941638735,"hari":"2020-03-23 10:20:26"},{"harga":18.103742695096674,"hari":"2020-03-23 10:25:02"},{"harga":18.1144523202333,"hari":"2020-03-23 10:28:55"},{"harga":18.104201546453393,"hari":"2020-03-23 10:32:38"},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`time`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) axis:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      type: "time",
      time: {
        unit: "hour",
        displayFormats: {
          hour: "HH:mm"
        }
      }
    }]
    ...
```

Be sure to use the ['bundled build' of Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build), or include moment.js *before* Chart.js.

Comment: hai brother how to show day like my image, see after 21:00 show day 24 Mar?

Comment: @taufik Try `displayFormats: { hour: "HH:mm D MMM"}`. See the [moment.js documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for a complete reference.